# Connect a set of nodes with another set of the same size without intersections

Tags: graph-theory

I am quite new to graphs (and could use some practice with math in general) and couldn't find a solution with zero intersections to this problem.

Assume you have two sets of 3 nodes (set H and set L) where each node (ex. h1, h2, h3) from one set should connect to every node on the other set (so l1, l2, l3). **Is there any way you could arrange the connections so that there are no intersections?**

Example of one edge intersection:
[one edge intersection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfahS.png)

Comment: (I don't mean to imply that you were wrong to ask this question - but this is the [three utilities problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_utilities_problem), which is very famous in graph theory, so it has been asked before, and there is no sense in reproducing the many good answers there.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov thank you, I didnt know this was a known problem in graph theory

Comment: I think the problem is not solvable! Thank you both for the answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution: A graph $G$ is planar then $|E(G)|\leq 3|v(G)|-6$. If furthermore it is triangle free, then $|E(G)| \leq 2|V(G)|-4$. For $K_{3,3}$, It doesn't contains triangle as it doesn't contain odd cycle. So apply the second formula we get: $9\leq 2*6-4=8$ which is not possible! So it cannot be planar.

To show $|E(G)| \leq 2|V(G)|-4$, we will use Euler's equation: $|V|-|E|+|F|$=2 for planar graph. Notice that if you count the total number of edges surrounding the faces, you count each edge twice. So $\sum_{a\in F(G)}{len(a)}=2|E(G)|$. Now since the graph has no triangle, each face is bounded by at least 4 edges. So $4|F(G)|\leq\sum_{a\in F(G)}{len(a)}=2|E(G)|$. Solve for $|F|$ in Euler's equation and substitute into the previous inequality to get the desired inequality. Hope I got it right.